# How do you change the Object Page layout?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, standard-objects

How do you make the Leads page look like the Custom object page where the fields/everything is shown without having to click into the links?

[image: I want to change the lead page so that it is the same as the Work object page]

[image: Work Object]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this may not be ideal, but you can switch to Lightning Experience (LEX). The UI in Lightning Experience aligns standard and custom objects so that they share a similar experience. You can access all of your fields, layouts, record types, validation rules, buttons, actions, links, triggers, and Lightning Pages (a.k.a. FlexiPages) all from the central hub for the object, regardless if it is standard or custom.

### Standard Object

[image: Standard Object in Object Builder]

### Custom Object

[image: Custom Object in Object Builder]

Comment: Lightning UI is cool, have to start using it. Thanks for sharing didn't knew about it.

Answer (score 4):

Its standard object, hence the setup menu is different. You cannot customize it.

You can still navigate to setup, `Build` -> `Customize` -> `Lead` to access different links.

[image]